# youtube videois not displaying after remove() in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I have added remove on close function.so the you will will be closed.But later if i want see the video in click it not displaying the function remove which i have given close function is completely removed the YouTube video

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.Turkey').click(function () {

    $('#Turkey').fadeIn(1000);

    return false;
});

$(' #close').click(function () {
    $('#Turkey').fadeOut(300);
    $("#autoplayvideoframe").remove();
});
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/narayana_85/dYd26/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.Turkey').click(function () {
          var link="http://www.youtube.com/embed/e0KijUV9jv4"
          $('#Turkey').fadeIn(1000);
          $("#autoplayvideoframe").attr('src',link).show();

          return false;
      });

      $(' #close').click(function () {
          $('#Turkey').fadeOut(300);
          $("#autoplayvideoframe").removeAttr("src").hide();
      });
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kqYYn/15/)

Comment: thanks for your help, But if i close the YouTube video still play's in background where i can hear sound

Comment: Thanks Hoho ot's worked, But it blinking when it opens but right it works for me

Comment: @user3500643 if it helps upvote it and accept as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you do not need to remove iframe or hide src.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.Turkey').click(function () {

    $('#Turkey').fadeIn(1000);

    return false;
});

$(' #close').click(function () {
    $('#Turkey').fadeOut(300);
});
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dYd26/8/)